# Django query to filter date range

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-queryset, django-orm

I have a model which contains date range i want to filter the data based on the range date
that is i want the data who's date range is 90 days from today's date.

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    start_end_date = ranges.DateTimeRangeField(validators= 
                                                       [validate_range_date_time])
```

so when we select the start date on page the end date will popoulate the same date but i cannot concatenate filter just by today date + timedelta(days=90) this is one single date and the field is date range, so how can i filter the date range data which is 90 days from now.

the model stores start_end_date as

```
'start_end_date': DateTimeTZRange(datetime.datetime(2022, 11, 29, 9, 15), datetime.datetime(2022, 11, 29, 10, 0),



 Mymodel.objects.filter(start_end_date__contains=timezone.now() + timezone.timedelta(days=90))

timezone.now() + timezone.timedelta(days=90) = datetime.datetime(2022, 11, 29, 22, 52, 7, 759648)
```

the query is giving empty set

Comment: i should only filter for date but the model field is DateTimeTZRange

Comment: Do you want to query for the `start_end_date` instances that **overlap** with the 90 day period, or do you want to query for the `start_end_date` instances that **are fully contained within** the 90 day period? This makes a difference in how to approach the problem, and it is unclear in your question.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't used this field myself, but in base of what i read from [documentaition](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/postgres/fields/#std-fieldlookup-rangefield.contained_by), it should be like this:

```
from psycopg2.extras import DateTimeTZRange

Mymodel.objects.filter(
    start_end_date__contained_by=DateTimeTZRange(
        timezone.now(),
        timezone.now() + timezone.timedelta(days=90)
    )
)
```

to check if any `start_end_date` field is in 90 days from now, you should also pass a datetime range.

edited:

```
from psycopg2.extras import DateTimeTZRange

Mymodel.objects.filter(
    start_end_date__contained_by=DateTimeTZRange(
        timezone.now(),
        timezone.now() + timezone.timedelta(days=90),
    start_end_date__lower_inc=False
    )
)
```

Comment: this works but query returns start and end date with DateTimeTZRange(datetime.datetime(2022, 9, 1, 0, 15, 7, 41008), datetime.datetime(2022, 11, 30, 0, 15, 7, 41102), '[)') so  it will also filter for today's date

Comment: if the date for the model is set to today() it wil filter that

Comment: @jimmy ```Regardless of the bounds specified when saving the data, PostgreSQL always returns a range in a canonical form that includes the lower bound and excludes the upper bound, that is [).``` from documentation

Comment: i think you can achieve what you said with this lookup_field ```lower_inc``` https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/postgres/fields/#lower-inc

Comment: @jimmy check the edited code

Answer (score 1):

As it's a `DateTimeRangeField`, I think your result can be achieved by using `startswith` and `endswith` just like that:

```
max_date = timezone.now() + timezone.timedelta(days=90)
MyModel.objects.filter(start_end_date__startswith__gte=timezone.now(), start_end_date__endswith__lte=max_date)
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score -1):

I think you could design the model more easily.

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    start_date = models.DateTimeField()
    end_date = models.DateTimeField()
```

Then you can find objects like the following.

```
target_time = timezone.now() + timezone.timedelta(days=90)
MyModel.objects.filter(start_date__lte = target_time).filter(end_date__gte = target_time)
```